# what is Dspace DSpaceMETSGenerator for?

Tags: dspace, apache-cocoon

What is the purpose of the METS Generator in Dspace? How does it get called, and for what purpose exactly? Is there any docs that explain properly its role ?
I'm trying to figure out its original intent

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`DspaceMETSGenerator` is the `DSpace XMLUI` class that prepares the data of an Item,Community,Collection for transformation into html from an intermediary format named METS hence the name `DSpaceMETSGenerator`. You can see the raw METS of an item by going to [dspace.url]/metadata/handle/[handle-prefix]/[handle-suffix]/mets.xml

The heavy lifting of the transformation from database objects to mets.xml is delegated to subclasses of org.dspace.app.xmlui.objectmanager.AbstractAdapter e.g. org.dspace.app.xmlui.objectmanager.ItemAdapter. `DSpaceMETSGenerator` decides which adapter to delegate to and applies the necessary configuration to it.

Comment: I kinda solved the problem so far. But yeah will do as soon as I run in some turbulent zone again ;)

Comment: Actually, i would like to add some RDFa in my resulting page. Although the RDFa should be attribute on the tag/balise around the metadata elements. Hence generaly speaking i'm seeking some advise to do that, or else is it possible to see the all document with the mets data in it, before it goes to the XSL for visual transformation ?